# Merge sublists of a list in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I have a list given as:

```
l <- list("1"=list("a"=c(1,2,3), "b"=c(6,7,8), "c"=c(9,10,11)), "2"=list("a"=c(22,23,34),"b"=c(31,32,38), "c"=c(59,120,131)))
```

What I want to do is to unlist the sublists and concatenate them by the names, such as:

```
l2 <- mapply(c, l[["1"]], l[["2"]], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
> l2
$a
[1]  1  2  3 22 23 34

$b
[1]  6  7  8 31 32 38

$c
[1]   9  10  11  59 120 131
```

What to do, when I have multiple (e.g. 40-50) of these sublists (so not "1" and "2", but "1" to "50"), how do I merge them in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tranpose` from `purrr` and then `unlist` each element to get vector.

```
l2 <- purrr::transpose(l) %>% purrr::map(unlist, use.names = FALSE)
l2

#$a
#[1]  1  2  3 22 23 34

#$b
#[1]  6  7  8 31 32 38

#$c
#[1]   9  10  11  59 120 131
```

Answer (score 1):

Using combination of `lapply()` and `unlist()`:

```r
setNames(
  lapply(
    vects, 
    function(v) unlist(lapply(l, function(y) y[[v]]), use.names = FALSE)
  ), 
  vects
)

# $a
# [1]  1  2  3 22 23 34
# 
# $b
# [1]  6  7  8 31 32 38
# 
# $c
# [1]   9  10  11  59 120 131
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the lists by subseting them with their names.

```
x <- unlist(l, FALSE, FALSE)
y <- unlist(lapply(l, names))
z <- unique(y)
lapply(setNames(z, z), function(i) unlist(x[i==y]))
#$a
#[1]  1  2  3 22 23 34
#
#$b
#[1]  6  7  8 31 32 38
#
#$c
#[1]   9  10  11  59 120 131
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` with `do.call` in `base R`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) c(...), unname(l)))
#$a
#[1]  1  2  3 22 23 34

#$b
#[1]  6  7  8 31 32 38

#$c
#[1]   9  10  11  59 120 131
```